# Using fgets() to put a character into an array creates automatic input?

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

I want to take in a single character of input that the user types in, and then print it back out using the printf() and fgets() methods (this is all a part of a bigger program, but this is the isolated problem).

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>
char input[1];    

int main(){
  printf("Please enter the minimum value the random number can be: ");
  fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
  printf("\n%c", input[0]);
}
```

## How I expect the above code to work

I would think that it would print out the printf() message, and then wait for input from the user. No matter what they typed in, I would then expect it to take the first character of that input and print it back out again one line down.

## How the above code actually works

The program prints the initial printf() statement, then prints out a blank line underneath, and then the program terminates.

Why in the world is this?? Why is the code responding in that way and not how I expect?

Comment: Read the [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html).

Comment: `fgets(buffer,size,file)` reads at most `size-1` bytes. That's why.

Comment: Strings in C/C++ are null-terminated, so `fgets` would like to have space for both the string and terminating zero character. 1 characters is enough to fit zero character only.

Comment: @yeputons, please don't conflate the two languages especially when the question itself is C-specific - C++ string are *nothing* like C strings.

Comment: @paxdiablo C++ has multiple flavors of strings (including C strings), but, yup, confusion was unnecessary.

Comment: @user2357112 I haven't seen that before, is that the "official" manual? I was told that there was no official manual or 'official' documentation for C.

Comment: @Guy Heh?? The standard I did quote in my answer is **the official** documentation of C.

Comment: and, none of the online manuals are authoritative, they are informative.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I meant that I had never seen that webpage before (not that text, as obviously you put it in your answer). If your quote was from the official documentation of C, doesn't that make it authoritative?

Comment: @Guy Right, to clear the confusion, the quote I used is from the official C standard and that is authoritative, the other online links you may get (google for 'man fgets') are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `C11`, chapter 7.21.7.2, `fgets()` synopsis and description, (*emphasis mine*)

> ```
> char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> The `fgets` function reads **at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n`**
>   from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by `s`. [...]

and regarding the reason behind *one less*,

> [...] A
>   null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

In your case, the value of `n` supplied is `1`, hence `fgets()` actually does not read anything!!

**Solution:** You need to change your array size two 2, one element for the input and one element for the terminating null.

Comment: Ah, this explains it then! The documentation I was reading did not mention that caveat. Changing it to a 2 solved my problem! (I'll accept this answer when the timer allows me)

Answer (score 1):

You need space to store the NUL terminator so providing a buffer of size one means that no data entry is possible.

It's likely `fgets` is detecting this and just exiting. Changing the array size to `2` causes it to wait for input.